Can a Wirtinger type of argument reveal that a holomorphic, not necessarily entire, function with constant modulus is constant?
I've seen a few proofs of the statement that a holomorphic, not necessarily entire, function with constant modulus is constant. They all use the Cauchy-Riemann equations in one way or another.
When I was out cycling an hour ago the thought struck me that maybe we could prove this faster and more elegantly using the Wirtinger derivatives. Now I've come up with the following argument, and I would like to ask if it's correct or flawed.
If the modulus of a function
is constantly zero, then the function itself is constantly zero, which makes the conclusion of the statement trivially true, so suppose that $f$ is a holomorphic, not necessarily entire, function whos modulus is constantly equal to some non-zero $k$.
Then the square of the modulus,  $f(z) \overline {f(z)}$, is constantly equal to $k^2$, and if we take the second Wirtinger derivative of both sides of the equation $k^2 = f(z) \overline {f(z)}$, we get $$0 = f(z) \frac {\partial} {\partial \bar z} \overline {f(z)} = f(z) \overline {\frac {\partial} {\partial z} f(z)} = f(z) \overline {f'(z)}$$
From the assumptions it follows that $f(z)$ doesn't vanish anywhere in its domain, which means that $\overline {f'(z)}$ and consequently also $f'(z)$ must vanish everywhere. Hence $f$ is constant.

Please reserve $\times$ for cross product of vectors unless you’re doing elementary school arithmetic. You’re missing a conjugate.  You need $\overline{f’(z)}$. Also, the $0$ should be at the beginning, not the end.

I can see why 0 should be at the beginning but not why there should be a bar over $f'(z)$. What about a dot instead of a cross to indicate multiplikation?

You really do not need any symbol. How did $\dfrac{\partial\bar f}{\partial\bar z}$ turn into $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}$?

Isn't that a known property of the Wirtinger derivatives? I've written the multiplication without a symbol now and have put $0$ at the beginning.

No, the known property is the complex conjugate of that. Just write it out! (And you should use \partial instead of \delta.)

Ok, I will try \partial, but I don't understand exactly what formula you mean. The formula    I used is mentioned in  a video about Wirtinger derivatives.

It’s wrong. The simplest example will show that (try $f(z)=z^2$). Try using the definitions to write a proof. Either you missed something or it’s another untrustworthy video.

It seems like I remembered the formula incorrectly. What's stated in the video agrees with what you're suggesting, so I will try to correct the argument.

It’s fine now. Perhaps next time you should double-check your sources before posting and … insisting rather stubbornly.

I appreciate your comments and am glad to hear that the argument is fine now.

This argument seems correct to me. The only thing I would add is to emphasize that when using the product rule we apply that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}} = 0$ because $f$ is holomorphic.

Yes, maybe I should have written that as an additional step in the calculation. Good to hear that the argument seems correct.

You did miss a significant error, although it doesn’t substantively affect the argument.

What error would that be?

The one I’ve been correcting for an hour. This comment was to @mathperson314.

Also, the open mapping theorem asserts that a non-constant holomorphic function (on a non-empty open, whether it's entire or not) maps open sets to open... so cannot map to a circle, etc.
